# Recover keystore password when saved by Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, passwords, keystore

Good morning,

I (stupidly) forgot the passwords (it's the same for both cases) of my Android keystore, except that I did "Remember passwords" so I don't need to remember them .

Except that I changed my PC and whoever keeps the key and its passwords could break down at any moment, and I wouldn't really like to lose the key permanently, otherwise I won't be able to publish my app on play store.

[keystore popup in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzaRh.png)

I tried several different passwords with the length displayed by the "**********" in Android Studio, but it never works unfortunately.
And with new versions, no file displays passwords in plain text, either *** or hash.

Do you have a solution to recover these passwords since Android Studio keeps them?
I'm on the latest version of the IDE, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible if you have Play Signing enables. First to check if you have Play Signing turned on login to the console, select the app and then select "App Integrity" from the menu, on that page you will see an app signing tab. If it is switched on that you can follow the instructions here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756#lost

Hope this helps

Ref. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/208735127/i-forgot-the-keystore-password-for-my-application-is-it-possible-to-reset-the-keystore-pass-thanks?hl=en

Answer (score -1):

look in the build.gradle file in the app directory of your project.
I forgot mine and looked in a backup of my projects.